# Print owner and file name of all files created in 2014

Tags: unix

I have to print the owner and name of all files inside a directory, but only if the file was created in 2014.

For example:

```
$ ls /dir
file1
file2
file3
```

If file1 was created in 2013 but file2 and file3 in 2014, then I need a command like:

```
$ command /dir
userName file2
userName file3
```

Where userName is the owner of the file.

Answer (score 0):

This is a good application for `find`:

```
find /dir -type f -newermt 2014-01-01 -printf "%u %P\n"
```

This will print owner and file name of all  files *modified* in 2014. In general there is no way to get the creation time of a file.

Comment: Note that this is using some heavy-duty (read 'useful') GNU extensions to standard `find`.  If the OP's Unix is using GNU `find`, all is well.  If not, the OP has some more work to do to translate that into standard `find`.